# i3blocks config doesn't work on Arch install, but works fine on debian

Tags: arch-linux, i3-window-manager

I recently moved to Arch from Debian (*and loving it so far*), but I have a slight UI issue. I pulled my i3blocks config from my debian install, but my weather and volume modules do not load for some reason and I can figure out why. I'm hoping someone can help me.

```
[weather]
command=curl wttr.in/Nottingham?format="%C" | sed 's/^//'
interval=1
#interval=1800
color=#64a964

# Volume indicator
[volume]
label=
instance=Master
#instance=PCM
interval=1
signal=10
command=/usr/share/i3blocks/volume 1 pulse
color=#64a964
```

Other modules in the config load fine (time and date), but I'm having issues with these two. The weather script in particular is confusing, as it runs fine in the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed solve these issues.

**Weather block**

I solved the weather block by exporting the command to it's own separate script. I then used i3blocks to call this script instead.
Not sure why, but this solved the issue.

```
  weather=$(curl -s wttr.in/Nottingham?format="%C" | sed 's/^/ /')
  echo $weather
```

Then in i3blocks.conf

```
[weather]
command=/path/to/script
interval=1800
```

**Volume Block**

I checked that the command path was correct, as my Arch install had a slightly different path than my original debian install. I also noticed that the volume script was non-executable, so I modified this using

```
chmod +x <filename>
```